# To search images in S3 folder by keywords

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

What is the best and simple way to search and get images list from S3 by using English keywords. Or do I have to use the Rekognition to store all the image metadatas into database?

My development is using Php.

Comment: You can search by prefix

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

// Use the high-level iterators (returns ALL of your objects).
try {
    $objects = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

// Use the plain API (returns ONLY up to 1000 of your objects).
try {
    $result = $s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

so this code will return you all objects in your bucket, you can add logic that only iff the key contains the extension 'jpg', 'jpeg' , and 'png' then only you have to print the key/name of object

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the objects and find the ones you are looking for

In pseudo-code

```
connect to S3

list thru all buckets ( or specify a bucket )

for object in bucket.objects.all
    if object.key = your search criteria
        do something
```

I have a code does this for me in python, let me know if you like me to post it, since you are using php I gave you the logic in pseudo code above